# newbie hibernate first level cache confusion

Tags: hibernate

I'm just geting to grips with hibernate. Little bit confused.

I just wanted to watch the operation of the first level cache, which I understood to batch up queries until the end of the session.

But if I create an object, hibernate saves it immediately, so that when I later update it in the same transaction, it has to do an update too:

```
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Test1 test1 = new Test1();
test1.setName("Test 1");
test1.setValue(10);
// Touch it
session.save(test1);

System.out.println("At checkpoint 1");

test1.setValue(20);

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I see the sql for the save, then 'At checkpoint 1', then the sql for the update. Do I have something set up wrong or am I misunderstanding hibernate's first level cache? Is there a good document on the first level cache - I didn't find anything in the hibernate docs, but I could easily have missed it..

Thanks!

Comment: Ah - great! Thank you - that solves the question of why it saves it right away. I changed it from generated and supplied the id myself, and now both sql statements execute at the end.
I'm still a little confused as to why there are two sql statements if I supply the id. I would have thought hibernate could run the insert using the CURRENT values in the object, instead of the original values. Then there would be no need to do an insert AND an update. But perhaps that's asking a lot? Are there docs on what hibernate does and doesn't do in these situations or should I just look at the code?

Comment: Maybe they are afraid that your database contains a trigger which does something on insert and something else on update. In that case the behaviour would be changed by caching the updates?

Comment: Thanks Cobusve - that could well be it. Although I'm also seeing that with multiple updates to the same object (remembering to call SaveOrUpdate between each update), only the final state of the object is updated to the database - which means that any intermediate triggers - for example updating a history table of updates made - would not get fired, so perhaps they're not that worried about triggers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first version of your question, you'll find some answers in the chapter [10.2. Making objects persistent](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent) of the documentation:

> Newly instantiated instances of a a
>   persistent class are considered
>   transient by Hibernate. We can make a
>   transient instance persistent by
>   associating it with a session:
>
> ```
> DomesticCat fritz = new DomesticCat();
> fritz.setColor(Color.GINGER);
> fritz.setSex('M');
> fritz.setName("Fritz");
> Long generatedId = (Long) sess.save(fritz);
> ```
>
> If `Cat` has a generated identifier,
>   the identifier is generated and
>   assigned to the `cat` when `save()` is
>   called. If `Cat` has an assigned
>   identifier, or a composite key, the
>   identifier should be assigned to the
>   `cat` instance before calling
>   `save()`. You can also use `persist()`
>   instead of `save()`, with the
>   semantics defined in the EJB3 early
>   draft.
>
> - `persist()` makes a transient instance persistent. However, it does
>     not guarantee that the identifier
>     value will be assigned to the
>     persistent instance immediately, the
>     assignment **might** happen at flush time.
>     `persist()` also guarantees that it
>     will not execute an `INSERT` statement
>     if it is called outside of transaction
>     boundaries. This is useful in
>     long-running conversations with an
>     extended Session/persistence context.
> - `save()` does guarantee to return an identifier.
>     **If an `INSERT` has to be
>     executed to get the identifier ( e.g.
>     "identity" generator, not "sequence"),
>     this `INSERT` happens immediately**,
>     no matter if you are inside or outside
>     of a transaction. This is problematic
>     in a long-running conversation with an
>     extended Session/persistence context.

BTW, if you look closely at the `save()` method, you'll notice that it indeed returns `Serializable` (the assigned identifier).

---

Now, regarding the updated version of your question, Hibernates uses an [`ActionQueue`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/engine/ActionQueue.java.html) that *holds the DML operations queued as part of a session's transactional-write-behind semantics. DML operations are queued here until a flush forces them to be executed against the database.*

When you call `save()` or `persist()`, an *insert action* that contains a copy of the values of the entity to be inserted is added to the "insertions" list.

Then, you modify the persistent entity and, at flush time, the entity is detected as dirty and another action (an *update action*) is added for that same entity with another copy of that entity's values: the pending insert action is not updated with the new values.

And this results in two DML operations (an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE`).

This behavior is somehow explained in the comments of [HHH-2588](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2588). It is (certainly) not optimal but this is how the current Hibernate implementation does work and I am not aware of all the details to explain why Hibernate doesn't perform this optimization (I guess it's not that simple). But feel free to submit a patch :)

Comment: Pascal, thank you so much for your full and clear answer. I don't know where you find the patience for such noob questions, but I am very grateful for it :-)

Comment: @Bruce You're welcome. Actually, it's far from a noob question IMO, I find it pretty interesting (and many people don't even try to understand things like you currently do).